# Implementing of social media login into spring security

Tags: java, spring, facebook, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring 3 and spring security. I'm integrating social accounts for instance: Facebook, Twitter, and Google. I'm using there javascript sdk version but my issue is I can register a user but I'm not sure how to authenticate them.

For example:

When user clicked on any of the Links(Facebook, Twitter, Google) new dialog box is opened after authenticated successfully I can get their basic profile details: email, id, name, images and I passed all this information to my controller using ajax which call service and dao to save user if user is not already registered.

Till here everything is working fine for me. I used user id and encrypt them using salt and save it into the database as a password(I'm not sure if this a correct way to deal with it or not) but now my confusion is how can I authenticate a user and allow them to login into the system.

My security.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Configuration for master level user login -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <!-- <csrf /> -->
        <headers>
            <cache-control />
            <content-type-options />
            <hsts />
            <frame-options />
            <xss-protection />
        </headers>
        <!-- requires-channel="https" -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/facebook-login*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/validateUserCredentials*"
            access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/register*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/activation*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/restore*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resend*" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/license*"
            access="hasAnyRole('${role.admin}', '${role.master}')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="hasAnyRole('${role.admin}', '${role.master}', '${role.owner}', '${role.simple}')" />
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/logged"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" />
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
            <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
        </session-management>
        <remember-me token-validity-seconds="86400" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" />

    <beans:bean id="saltSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
        <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" name="userAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.luffy.security.AuthenticationUserDetailService">
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Any help will be appreciated. I did everything that I can to resolve this issue but I'm not able to figure out any reliable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are implementing Facebook Authentication.

**Solution (1):**

On successful response from Facebook you can call server API to update authentication table with facebook user credentials such as username/email and OAuth access_token.

```
$.post('api/fblogin', {access_token: accessToken}, function(response) {});
```

**Solution (2):**
Custom Security Handler. Here you can initiate your custom HTTP request to Facebook and upon successful completion you allow user to access the site.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.restfb.*;;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        String fb_access_token = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("fb_access_token"));

        //fb user
        Authentication auth = null;
        try {
            FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(fb_access_token);
            User user = fbClient.fetchObject("me",com.restfb.types.User.class);
            String email = user.getEmail();
            String gender = user.getGender();
            String pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.getId() + "/picture?type=normal"; 
            //Your DB implementation

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FacebookOAuthException("FB","OAuth",5002, null, null, "", "");
        }       
    }
}
```

spring-security.xml

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" >
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.mi.common.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I was looking for something like this from long time but I still have one problem with your solution which is When I authenticate the user from FB how can I authenticate & authorize same user in spring so that spring can validate the user. Sorry if you found it stupid I'm stuck at this from quite some time

Comment: Ive added custom implementation? Hope it helps. Little bit of configuration is needed at spring side to handle customAuthentication.